# What's the proper way of setting up a subdomain on a https domain?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4

Say I have the following VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost demo.example.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@WPQA
    DocumentRoot /var/www/demo
    ServerName demo.example.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>    
<VirtualHost example.com:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@WPQA
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName example.com


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I'm trying to bypass SSL for `demo.example.com`, however, the subdomain is returning the same content as `example.com`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Does demo.example.com answer on HTTP or HTTPS?  If HTTP, then the 2nd virtual host definition can't be entering into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file has demo.example.com set up on port 80 (hence, HTTP only) and example.com set up on port 443 (HTTPS only).

Note that even if you set them both up on 443, you will have two problems:

1. You cannot share the certificate between example.com and demo.example.com.  Typical/normal certificates will cover the blank domain name and www. (i.e. example.com and www.example.com) so demo.example.com will be considered as unrelated and will show an SSL error in the browser.  One solution is to buy a wildcard certificate *.example.com, which is way more expensive, or you need a separate certificate just for demo.example.com.
2. If you get a separate certificate, then to host both example.com and demo.example.com, you will need to use something called [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which unfortunately doesn't work for users on IE/Windows XP.  That is why it isn't used often.  You can find out [more about setting up SNI with Apache](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) here.  Wildcard domains don't have this problem, but as I mentioned before, the downside is that they are more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Your virtual host configuration should be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@WPQA
    ServerName demo.example.com
    ServerAlias demo.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/demo

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note the use of the wildcard `*` for the `<VirtualHost *:80>` line. I also set a `ServerAlias` as well as the `ServerName`.